# IceFaces 2 - navigation rule sometimes does not apply

Tags: navigation, icefaces

I have a little IceFaces project. Opening the base url **localhost:8080/myContextPath** opens a file called index.jsp with the following content:

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <jsp:forward page="faces/search.xhtml" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This first redirects to faces/search.xhtml. The page is dispayed without any problems. The browsers address bar displays **localhost:8080/myContextPath** as expected.

Located on the search.xhtml page, there is a submit button, looking like this:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" actionListener="#{searchBean.submitButton}" action="#{searchBean.navigate}" />
```

Clicking on that button triggers the actionListener and then the **navigate**-action, which returns a simple **success**.

The navigation rule itself looks like this:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/search.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/search.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The navigation rule should apply, as far as I understand, under any circumstances.

Sadly, sometimes this doesn't work. To be precise, every second time it is not working. Clicking on the submit button triggers first the action listener and then the webapp is "thinking" for about 1-2 seconds and then redirects to a broken page.

The difference between the normal way

localhost:8080/myContextPath -> click submit button -> localhost:8080/myContextPath

and the broken way is, that it looks like this in the address bar

localhost:8080/myContextPath -> click submit button -> localhost:8080/myContextPath/faces/search.xhtml.

The page is then broken, cause all javascript and css files cannot be found any more, cause they are referenced with an relative path.

Do you have any idea, which problems can cause this broken navigation?

In short words: Loading the page for the first time, is a simple redirect in the index.jsp page: index.jsp -> jsp:formward -> search.xhtml. Then I click on the submit button and the navigation rule reloads search.xhtml. Now I press a second time the submit button and now the navigation rule is not working any more. Instead the url changes in the address bar to localhost:8080//faces/search.xhtml instead of remaining at localhost:8080/.

Best regards
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, what actually happens is that you are doing a server side forward and not a client side reDirect, that is why though your address bar displays "myContextPath" 
it is already under "faces/search.xhtml"

```
<jsp:forward page="faces/search.xhtml" />
```

Basically when you click "navigate" change the rule from /search.xhtml to /faces/search.xhtml